# Overload python operator "<<" as C++ iostream

Tags: python, iostream, operator-keyword

I am reading the *python cookbook 2nd*, one sample in "*chap 2.13 Using a C++-like iostream Syntax*“, I try to understand how the *self* works in the code.

```
class IOManipulator(object):
    def __init__(self, function=None):
        self.function = function
    def do(self, output):
        self.function(output)
def do_endl(stream):
    stream.output.write('\n')
    stream.output.flush()
endl = IOManipulator(do_endl)
# my understanding, all above is about make a newline and flush sys.stdout,

class OStream(object):
    def __init__(self, output=None):
        if output is None:
            import sys
            output = sys.stdout
        self.output = output
        self.format = '%s'
    def __lshift__(self, thing):
        if isinstance(thing, IOManipulator):
            thing.do(self) 
            # It make no sense to me, why the function belongs to 
            # another class's instance need call (self)
        else:
            self.output.write(self.format % thing)
            self.format = '%s' # <- is it necessary? seems to be not.
        return self  # <- why return a "self" here? 
        # If comment this line out, 
        # python raise a TypeError when execute to the "<< 1"
        # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'NoneType' and 'int'

def example_main():
    cout = OStream()
    cout << "The average of " << 1 << " and " << 3 << " is " << (1+3)/2 << endl

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example_main()
# emits:
#> The average of 1 and 3 is 2
```

the "self" is `<__main__.OStream object at 0x7fc28cd92410>`, I know it is a instance of OStream class, maybe could be taken as a C pointer.

Comment: `return self` is required because you're using the `<<` on the output of first `<<` operation and so on...

Comment: Note when if a function misses a `return` python does a `return None`.  Hence the error you see (`<<` returns a `None` and `None << x` isn't defined).

Comment: Anyway `return self` is **not** strictly required. You have to put `return something` but that `something` could be something else, like a new `OStream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer the questions you put in the comments:

---

```
if isinstance(thing, IOManipulator):
    thing.do(self) 
    # It make no sense to me, why the function belongs to 
    # another class's instance need call (self)
```

You pass `self` (the output stream) to `thing` (which will be an `IOManipulator` such as the `endl` operation), so that the `IOManipulator` class can execute a function (see below, `IOManipulator.do`) on the output stream.

```
def do(self, output):
    self.function(output)
```

For the maximum amount of confusion, the first `self` in this snippet is NOT the `self` you passed to it in `OStream`! The `self` you pass to `thing.do` gets set as the `output` variable.

---

```
return self  # <- why return a "self" here?
```

You return the `OStream` instance here so you can chain operations. Note that python parses the line `a << b << c` as `(a << b) << c`. The `(a << b)` part needs to return its updated self in order to then be able to do `<< c` on it and make sense. If you comment `return self` out, you end up with `None << c` because then the function will return `None`.

---

```
self.format
```

I'm unsure what the author intended with this, it seems unnecessary. The line `self.output.write(self.format % thing)` could also have been written as `self.output.write(str(thing))`.

---

As a sidenote: this may be an example of how you could implement a new operator, but this specific operator is **terribly** un-pythonic: it would result in really ugly and confusing code. In the real world, try to use the features the language already has.